# How To reverse a URL with hyphens in the name?

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Application, with a file like the next one

`app_something/url.py`:

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

slashless_router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=True)
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'complex-name', views.ComplexNameModelViewSet)
router.register(r'simple', views.SimpleModelViewSet)

app_name='something'

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

It works perfect. Or that is what I used to think. Now, I'm trying to add Tests (Yep, my bad they should be there first)

BUT, now in my `test_complex_name_api.py`:

```
from django.urls import reverse

from rest_framework import status

from app_something import models, serializers

SIMPLE_MODEL_NAME_URL = reverse('something:simple-list')
COMPLEX_MODEL_NAME_URL = reverse('something:complex-name-list')

# ...
# My Tests
```

But, when I run my tests I got next error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'complex-name-list' not found. 'complex-name-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

`SimpleModel` works pretty cool. So, I think it's related to the name. But I haven't found which should be the name pattern to use? Should I rename the url or can I still use in this way and I'm only missing the part of the docs which talk about this? (I read from: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRF using [`basename`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage) for reverse viewset urls. By default it's evaluating based on queryset provided in viewset, but can override it by providing custom value to router directly:

```
router.register(r'complex-name', views.ComplexNameModelViewSet, basename='complex-name')

COMPLEX_MODEL_NAME_URL = reverse('something:complex-name-list')
```

Comment: It works. Basically with the ```basename``` attribute it works. But, I dont understand why I have to rewrite and doesn't work like ```router.register(r'simple', views.SimpleModelViewSet)
``` and  ```reverse('something:simple-list')```, do you know why? (My doubt is because they are basically the same)

Comment: @joseglego I have a guess what's happenning here. DRF using as default basename lowercased model name from viewset's queryset. So to make `complex-name` works without overriding basename your model should be named `Complex-Name` which is obviuosly not a good choice for class name in python:)

Comment: Well, I'll be setting the basename even when they were the same. Just to be sure! Thanks so much! @neverwalkaloner